# Shiny: renderUI with Submit Button - How to make renderUI react to selectInput without Submit Button being pressed?

Tags: r

**Short Version:** How do I get renderUI to react to a drop-down list that is in a wellPanel that contains a submitButton *without having to click the submitButton*?

**Long Version:** I am building a Shiny app to perform many different analyses on a large dataset. The user will select their analysis from a drop-down list at the top of a wellPanel. Depending on the analysis selected, I'd like to provide a different set of additional inputs/filters in the wellPanel with a submitButton at the bottom.

I would like the user to have to change the dynamic inputs, then click the submitButton for their inputs to take effect. However, I want the renderUI function to react to the drop-down list at the top *without* the submitButton being clicked. From what I've read, I think I need to use observeEvent or something similar, but I can't figure it out.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm building. Changing the drop-down list selection and clicking submit will change the inputs. Submit will also change the text rendered on the right. However, I need to uncouple the dynamic UI from the submit button. Any help is much appreciated.

ui.r:

```
library(shiny)    

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(4,wellPanel(
          selectInput("analysis", label = "Type of Analysis:", 
                    c("Award Total" = "total", 
                      "Award Average" = "average"),
                    width = validateCssUnit("70%")),
          uiOutput("filter_box"),
          submitButton()
               )),
      column(8, textOutput("sample_text"))
      )
  )
```

server.r:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$filter_box <- renderUI({
if(input$analysis == "total"){
  tagList(radioButtons(inputId = "input1", label = "Select One:",c("A", "B", "C"), selected = "A"))
} else {
  tagList(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "input2", label = "Select all that apply:",c("1","2","3","4","5")),
          dateRangeInput(inputId = "input3", label = "Enter Date Range"))
}
  })

  output$sample_text <- renderText({
if(input$analysis == "total"){
  input$input1
} else if(input$analysis == "average") {
  c(input$input2, input$input3)
}
  })

})
```

Comment: This question is more suited for [***stackoverflow.***](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: You're right. After about 24 hours with no response here I asked it over there and got my answer. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404693/shiny-make-renderui-react-to-drop-down-list-not-submitbutton) it is in case anyone wants to see that. Thank you.